# Draw counterplot according to a weighted graph

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot, igraph, ggnetwork

I would like to draw a counter-plot according to my weights in the graph. I used the below code for that:

```
edgelist <- read.table(text = "
V1 v2 weight
                       A B 1
                       B C 8
                       C D 6
                       D E 9
                       C F 12
                       F G 15",header=T)
g <- graph_from_data_frame(edgelist)

library(intergraph)

gnet<-asNetwork(g)

library(ggnetwork)
library(ggplot2)

#contour plot
ggnetwork(gnet) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = x, y = y, xend = xend, yend = yend)) +
  geom_edges(aes(size = weight),color = "#c7ceab") +
  geom_nodes(color = "red", size = 9.25) +
  geom_nodetext(aes (label = vertex.names), size=1.75) +
  theme_blank() +
   geom_density_2d()
  +  theme(axis.text = element_blank(),
                            axis.title = element_blank(),
                            panel.background = element_rect(fill = "white"),
                            panel.grid = element_blank())
```

However, It doesn't consider the weights of the graph. I like to have the density of the counterplot regarding the weights. Any idea how to fix them?

To reach such a plot, I used the above code. But If you have better suggestions I would be happy to hear it.

Comment: When you say "It doesn't consider the weights," what exactly is "it"? The density plot? How do you want the weights to factor into the contouring? Also just an FYI, as far as I can tell the `theme` specifications you made are all handled by `theme_blank`, and also isn't necessary for illustrating the problem

Comment: @camille By it I mean the density. I meant where the graph has more weights be more dense